# Hidden button reappears after reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which displays set of details such as student name, department and student status, student class and a 'no vacancy' button. If there is no vacancy for the particular class, and if I click the 'no vacancy' button in the page, the email will go and the student status will change. This is the workflow I have for my application.

My problem here is once I click the 'no vacancy' button it should be removed from the page. I tried that and that is also working. However when I reload the page the 'no vacancy' button is coming back to the page. I want to remove the button completely from the page once the email is sent.

Can any one of you help me in this?

```js
function noOpening() {
  var candidateName = "Hello"
  var candidateclass = "BE"

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/noopening/email",
    data: {
      'candidatename': candidateName,
      'candidateclass': candidateclass,
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.error == "Success") {
        alert("sent");
      } else {
        alert("cannot be sent");
      }
    }
  })
  document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 form-display">
  <label class="col-md-8" for="Candidate Name:">Candidate Name:</label>
  <label class="col-md-8" for="candidateName">{{candidate_name}}</label>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 form-display">
  <label class="col-md-8" for="Candidate class:">Candidate class:</label>
  <label class="col-md-8" for="candidateclass">{{candidate_class}}</label>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 form-display">
  <label class="col-md-8" for="Candidate status:">Candidate status:</label>
  <label class="col-md-8" for="candidatestatus">{{candidate_status}}</label>

</div>
<div id="loader" visibility="visible">
  <input type="button" id="hideButton" onclick="noOpening()" value="No opening">
</div>
```

Comment: HTTP is stateless. This means that any changes you make to the DOM *are not saved anywhere*. The next time you request the page from the server it will revert to its initial state. To work around this you need to manually store the state, either on the client or the server (the latter is by far the better idea) and then amend the page to reflect the state as it's rendered.

Comment: Yes thanks for the quick reply. Should I use the local storage for storing the state. for eaxmple shall I use document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = localstorage.'hidden';I tried it and its not working

Comment: That would work, however it depends on the level of security you need. If this is required to be a secure system, do not do this client side as it's trivial to get around (for example I can clear the localstorage in the browser in your example, and the button will re-appear). Given that users are booking courses I assume you have a method to identify these accounts on the server side, so I'd strongly suggest you store state there.

Comment: document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = localstorage.'hidden' and storeValue="hidden",document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility=localStorage.storeValue; I have tried these two ways and it's not working.